# Python pandas: filter columns in dataframe BEGINNING with pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have 2 columns called `eta` and `theta` in a pandas data frame.

I'm trying to select the column called `eta` only.

So far I have tried

```
df.filter(like='eta')
```

...however this selects both `eta` and `theta`.

I've also tried `pattern`, but this is an R command:

```
df.filter(pattern='^eta')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `regex` parameter of [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df.filter(regex=r'^eta')
```

Make sure to escape regex characters if needed, for instance if the columns start with `eta.`:

```
df.filter(regex=r'^eta\.')
```

If you have a doubt:

```
import re

target = 'eta'
df.filter(regex=fr'^{re.escape(target)}')
```